# How to push nuget package to an online server location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-server

I have just created a .Net class library which I need to be converted to a nuget package. I can create a local path for the nuget and push it there. However, I need other members of my team to be able to access it so they can use it in their project. So I decided to push it to a subdirectory in one of my websites.

So I created https://www.example.com/nuget and ran the following cli command

```
dotnet nuget push C:\Users\User1\source\repos\ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\LibraryName.1.0.0.nupkg -s https://www.example.com/nuget
```

and got the following response

> PUT https://www.example.com/nuget/
> OK https://www.example.com/nuget/ 1537ms
> Your package was pushed.

But when I try to add the package it throws an error and then I checked the location and discovered that the package is not there regardless of the fact that I got a response message that says "Your package was pushed".

Please how can I use a subdirectory in my website to store my nuget package and be able to access it from my application either from Visual Studio Package manager or other means?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the open source project: https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet and the reference configuration: https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/installation/local/